# Who is Noah Richards, and what is his relation to VS2010 crashing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash, stack-trace

Who is Noah Richards, and why is his name in the stack track of visual studio crashing? I refer to this specific stack trace.. (on a less important tack, why would this be happening? It is 100% reproducible after adding an opening parenthesis on a protected member of a class in a 50 project solution...

the error in question is:

```
AlignAssignments.dll!NoahRichards.AlignAssignments.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0xb2 bytes 


(Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.)

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x71 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
CodeAlignment.dll!CMcG.CodeAlignment.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0xa7 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
***AlignAssignments.dll!NoahRichards.AlignAssignments.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut)*** + 0xb2 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
CopyAsHtml.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Formatting.Implementation.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x16b bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.AutoBraceCommandFilter.GetTypingAction.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x28 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Impl.Basic.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Impl.Basic.Pairs.StringBasedPairCreator.OnTypingOpeningCharacter(Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Context.IContext context, char typedChar, System.Func<Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Pair.PairResult> typingAction) + 0x222 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Pairs.PairManager.HandleTypeChar(char typedChar, System.Func<Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.Pair.PairResult> action) + 0xe5 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.AutoBraceComplete.AutoBraceCommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0xc8 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
OrganizeVBImports.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.OrganizeVBImports.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x314 bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
QuickFind.dll!Microsoft.QuickFind.CommandBlocker.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x45 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x71 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x71 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x20 bytes   
SolutionNavigator.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Labs.CommandFilter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0xd3 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Exec(ref System.Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, System.IntPtr pvaIn, System.IntPtr pvaOut) + 0x163 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.SendCommand(System.Guid cmdGroup, uint cmdID, object inParam) + 0x6f bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.TextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) + 0x77 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.DispatchTextInputEvents.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.KeyProcessor p, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) + 0xb bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch<System.__Canon>.AnonymousMethod__1a() + 0x18 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(object errorSource, System.Action call) + 0x2d bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.Dispatch<System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs>(System.Action<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.KeyProcessor,System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs> action, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) + 0x150 bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.MakeHandler.AnonymousMethod__17(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs args) + 0x1c bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) + 0x31 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x29 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) + 0x3e bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0xbe bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x79 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) + 0x41 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) + 0x2c bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x1ff bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0x45 bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeCompleteComposition(System.Windows.Input.TextComposition composition) + 0x7e bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs e) + 0x41d bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs) + 0x9d bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x23b bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0x45 bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.UnsafeStartComposition(System.Windows.Input.TextComposition composition) + 0x74 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionManager.PostProcessInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs e) + 0x6ca bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs) + 0x9d bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x23b bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input) + 0x45 bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport) + 0x62 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessTextInputAction(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x189 bytes 
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(object param) + 0x2c6 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x53 bytes 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x42 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0xb4 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0xc6 bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, ref bool handled) + 0x35 bytes    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg) + 0x3d bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.PreTranslateInput(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.MSG[] lpmsg, bool handled) + 0xa5 bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/128945/noah-richards

Comment: He wrote a plugin that you are using.

Comment: My Google-Fu was weak...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2011/02/07/moving-on.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Noah Richards is one of the developers who worked on the 2010 release of Visual Studio.  He now works at google but he does have several Visual Studio extensions available on the Visual Studio gallery (and participated in several others).

It looks like you have his "Align Assignments" extension installed and it's running into an error while processing a key stroke.

- [Align Assignments Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cc34d69-c6f1-41e3-ac6e-5de071b3edc8)

He also participates on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128945/noah-richards)

Comment: Its a small world after all! Just seemed funny to have someones name within a stack trace! As it turns out I *DO* have that extension installed, however the crash appears consistently across a number of our machines, extensions or no. 

However, thank for answering both of my questions :)

Comment: Note that it isn't running into the error, it just happens to be in the command chain, courtesy VS's awesome everything-in-the-world-is-on-the-command-chain-callstack behavior :-p

Answer (score 12):

I'm famous!

If you are curious, I'm guessing the real culprit is the AutoBraceComplete extension (or *maybe* the CodeAlignment extension) messing things up in some way that breaks the command handling later on. AlignAssignments only forwards on Exec calls that aren't for the align assignments command. You can see what the exec for AlignAssignments looks like: https://github.com/NoahRic/AlignAssignments/blob/master/CommandFilter.cs

Side-note - I have no idea what I did to get my name in there; maybe it was set as my company name, and so VS decided I needed to be famous? Oh, and the "CMcG" is actually "Chris McGrath" who wrote the CodeAlignment extension, so someone should post a Stack Overflow question about him, too :) I shouldn't be the only famous person!

Comment: That's pretty cool.
I've got a feeling that a lot of the entries in the stack trace aren't relevant to the problem at all. 
In visual studio extensions, you have a method which checks whether the command is one you want to process. If it's not, you pass it on to the next.

So this would lead to a lot of entries getting added to the stack trace which has done nothing more than call the next link in the chain.

P.S. McGrath not McGraff ;)

Answer (score 5):

Noah was one of the developers on Visual Studio 2010. Believe he now works for Google. He's a [user here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128945/noah-richards), so perhaps he can post more details?

Comment: Having been able to reproduce this crash on machines with no Extensions, I have come to realise the cause is most likely elsewhere. Tomorrow I will try to grab a stack trace from a machine with a clean install and see if that helps to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you installed his [assignment alignment plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cc34d69-c6f1-41e3-ac6e-5de071b3edc8).

Comment: That I did, and jolly good it is too! However I've come to realise the stack trace in this case is misleading, as the crash is reproducible on machines with no extensions installed whatsoever. I guess I should grab a more useful one from one of theirs.

Answer (score 1):

Noah wrote a number of [extensions for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=noah%20richards&f%5B1%5D.Type=User&f%5B1%5D.Value=Noah%20Richards&f%5B1%5D.Text=Noah%20Richards) and it's possible that one of them happens to be loaded into your installation. Some ended up in the Power Tools and then in Visual Studio itself.

Comment: It is certainly possible in my case :) I am something of an extension junkie which can be like shooting yourself in the foot sometimes! However, in this particular case, this doesnt seem to be the cause. Or at least not the only cause :) Thanks for taking the time to answer though!